# How to put a string with HTML tags into an array or list?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a string that has some html tags in it and has multiple data in one string. I need to check if an element on the UI is present in that string. 
I was able to remove the tags but I am not sure how convert the string into an array or list so that it'll be easier to compare.

For example, the string coming from the database is:

```
<dl style="float: left; text-align: left; width: 50%;">
 <dt>
     Note1amp;M
 </dt>
 <dd>
     - This is an example
 </dd>
 <dt>
     Note2
 </dt>
 <dd>
     - Example 2
 </dd>
 <dt>
     Note 3
 </dt>
 <dd>
      - This is example 3
 </dd>
```

The text from the ui is

`Note1 - This is an example`

where Note1 is one element

This is an example is another element

So far what I have to remove tags and try to put in a list

```
public String[] verifyData(Strint txtFromDB) {
        String[] txt = new String[3];
        boolean compareValue1 = false, compareValue2 = false;
        boolean boolBack = false;
        WebElement abbreviation = driver.findElement(By.xpath(itemLocatorP1));
        WebElement fullName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(itemLocatorP2));
        String p1, p2;

        if((abbreviation.isDisplayed()) && (fullName.isDisplayed())) {
            try {
                getMenu().scroll_To_View_Web_Element(itemLocatorP1);
                p1 = getUITxt(itemLocatorP1); // getting a text from the UI;
                getMenu().scroll_To_View_Web_Element(itemLocatorP2);
                p2 = getUITxt(itemLocatorP2); // getting the second part text from the UI: 
                txt[0] = p1; //  Note 1
                txt[1] = p2; // - This is an example

                System.out.println("Array txt -> " + txt[0]);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                txt[0] = "Blank";
                System.out.println("Array txt Exception-> " + txt[0]);
            }
            // removing some html txt from the txtFromDB so that it can match with the UI
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("<dt>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dt>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("<dd>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dd>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll(">", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dl>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dl", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("<dl style=", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("float: left; text-align: left; width: 50%;", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("\"\"", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("amp;", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&rsquo;s", "’s");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&ndash;", "–");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
            System.out.println("DB Txt -> " + txtFromDB);

            String[] temp = txtFromDB.split("\\n");

            for(String x : temp) {
                System.out.println(x);
                if((x.contains(txt[0])) && (x.contains(txt[1]))) {
                    System.out.println(x + " from DB matches the UI -> " + txt[0] + txt[1]);
                    compareValue1 = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Still Searching.....");
                }
            }

            if(compareValue1 ) 
                boolBack = true;
            else
                boolBack = false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No such element was found in the page");
            txt[0] = "Blank";
            boolBack = false;
        }
        txt[2] = Boolean.toString(boolBack);
        return txt;
        }
```

So what I want to do is put `<dt>Note1</dt> and <dd>-This is an example</dd>` as one string like: `Note 1 - This is an example` in a list or array so that I can compare with any data on the UI.

Comment: You can probably do this more easily with a library that parses HTML such as beautifulsoup.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice beautifulsoup is for Python but I'll look for something that is similar for Java

Comment: My bad. I jump between both of the java and python tags and apparently didn't know which one I was looking at here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of figured it out, split the string based on double lines, then stored that in a list, and checked if the element I need to verify contains in that list

```
public void verifyEachCommonAcronymsAndAbbreviationsForAPB(String itemLocatorP1, String itemLocatorP2, String txtFromDB) {
        String[] txt = new String[3];
        boolean compareValue1 = false, compareValue2 = false;
        WebElement abbreviation = driver.findElement(By.xpath(itemLocatorP1));
        WebElement fullName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(itemLocatorP2));
        String p1, p2;

        if((abbreviation.isDisplayed()) && (fullName.isDisplayed())) {
            try {
                getMenu().scroll_To_View_Web_Element(itemLocatorP1);
                p1 = getUITxt(itemLocatorP1);
                getMenu().scroll_To_View_Web_Element(itemLocatorP2);
                p2 = getUITxt(itemLocatorP2);
                txt[0] = p1;
                txt[1] = p2;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                txt[0] = "Blank";
                System.out.println("Array txt Exception-> " + txt[0]);
            }
            // removing some html txt from the txtFromDB so that it can match with the UI
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("<dt>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dt>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("<dd>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dd>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll(">", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dl>", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("</dl", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("<dl style=", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("float: left; text-align: left; width: 50%;", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("\"\"", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("amp;", "");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&rsquo;s", "’s");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("&ndash;", "–");
            txtFromDB = txtFromDB.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
            //System.out.println("DB Txt -> " + txtFromDB);

            String[] splitArrDB = txtFromDB.split("\\n");

            List<String> acronymsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < splitArrDB.length; i++) {
                acronymsList.add(splitArrDB[i] + splitArrDB[i]);
            }


            for(String temp : acronymsList) {
                if((temp.contains(txt[0]))) {
                    System.out.println("Found " + txt[0] + " in the list");
                    compareValue1 = true;
                    break;
                }
                //System.out.println("still searching.....");
            }

            for(String x : acronymsList) {
                if((x.contains(txt[1]))) {
                    System.out.println("Found " + txt[1] + " in the list");
                    compareValue1 = true;
                    break;
                }
                //System.out.println("still searching.....");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

**With JSoup**

Instead of parsing it yourself you could look into using JSoup.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup

With JSoup you can remove all the html and get the text by:

```
String html = "<p>example</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
System.out.println(doc.text()); // doc.text() returns the text only from the html
```

This would output:

```
example
```

With JSoup you can also find elements with a certain id to separate them easier.

```
String html = "<dt>example</dt>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements dts = doc.getElementsByClass("dt");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into JSoup, looks much better then parsing it myself